# How can I convert IOrderedEnumerable<T> & IEnumerable<IGrouping<T>> & IEnumerable<T> to one common format?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I have 3 "Lists" all of different types and at the moment I have to pass them to 3 different functions to go output their contents because I don't know how to convert them to one type.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DynamicNode>>
IOrderedEnumerable<DynamicNode>
IEnumerable<DynamicNode>
```

How can I create a function to accept all 3 types so I can loop through them there without creating 3 different functions and duplicating code?

```
public void constructHtml(???? nodeList){
    foreach(dynamic child in nodeList){
        //etc..
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup I tried that, but that doesn't work for the IGrouping list.

Comment: how your method with `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DynamicNode>>` is different with others?

Comment: foreach(){
    foreach(){}
}

has list inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a generic method and check the type in the method. Something like

```
public void constructHtml<T>(T nodeList){
    // Check type T and do something with it
}
```